# Disk repair after hard reboot

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot

I run Windows 10 Insider Preview, and before today I've had absolutely no problem with it up till now.

I have an HP Pavilion laptop with 16gb of RAM, 1TB HDD, and an AMD APU

I went to a cafe which was a 20 minute walk, and I had my computer in sleep mode. When I got to the cafe, I woke it up and it was very unresponsive, so I tried a hard reboot. It hanged on the HP loading windows screen for 10 minutes, so I decided to hard reboot it again. On the third reboot, it went into automatic repair, and started to "repair disk errors". It's been doing this for **11 hours now.** I'm typing this on my iPad, but all of my important business documents are saved on my laptop and I need them

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Wait till it finishes.

Comment: Moving a hard drive that is not powered off is risky business and the fact that you say it was sleeping doesn't assure the drive was off.  Also note that you should always let a computer finish what it's doing unless you know a really good solution if a problem occurs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the obvious cheap shot of "restore the important data from backups"....

Get hold of an USB pendrive, or a CD or DVD which you can boot from. Then boot that rather than the failed windows installation. Use it to make a copy of all documents you want to rescue. Then either:

1. Try some sort of repair. First step is to find out what is wrong (hint: try to read the evenviewer logs while booted of that other medium. Depending on what is wrong you will want to try different methods of solving it.)
2. Or power off the laptop. Power it back up. In my win8.1/10 experience 11+ hours of repair loop never worked. But after powering it completely down a repair may suddenly work. No idea as to what or how. Just experience. I really wish I knew why.
3. Or reinstall a clean windows (and restore data from backup or from the recently made backup.)

If you find it hard to make a backup of the data and you did not encrypt your disk then you could also mount it in another desktop, an external eSATA or external USB case. That way rescuing the documents should be easy.